# Capistrano удаляет загруженные файлы

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

При развертывании приложения данные из папки `uploads/ckeditor/attachments` удаляются. Понятно что за все это отвечает `capistrano`.

Сделал вот такую настройку, но ситуация не изменилась

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{uploads/ckeditor/attachments}
```

Есть подозрение на то, что у меня в папке attachments есть директории, а в них уже файла. В итоге получается что путь у меня до файла

```
/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/38/1.mp3
```

Comment: Потому что папка, скорее всего, не та. Нужен путь относительно корня проекта. Что-то мне подсказывает, что в корне проекта у вас нет папки `uploads`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`linked_dirs` для капистрано задаются относительно корневого пути к проекту. А файлы с аплоада - хранятся в папке `public/uploads/...`. Вам нужно задать путь так:

```
set :linked_dirs, %w(public/uploads)
```

И все заработает.